# How to use DOCTYPE in Spring XML file

Tags: java, xml, spring, dtd

Most of the time we do not declare `DOCTYPE` in Spring. 
But I want to declare a DOCTYPE in my XML context file so that I can use `ENTITY` in my xml file.

**For example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
                  "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd"
    [<!ENTITY % crmHome SYSTEM "crm-home.dtd"> %crmHome;]
>
```

This gives many errors like...

```
 - Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "beans".

 - Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "beans".

    etc.....
```

What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

This works for me. Using Spring Framework V.4.2.1

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using schema validation anyway then you could just define the internal DTD subset sufficient to declare the parameter entity and not refer to the `http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd`:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans [
  <!ENTITY % crmHome SYSTEM "crm-home.dtd">
   %crmHome;
]>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

Comment: With this I get an error:  Element type "beans" must be declared.

Comment: I think you mean to say I have to fill all elements and attribute list in my crm-home.dtd file.

Comment: @Mawia there may be some way to configure the XML parser to validate only against the schema and not also against the DTD, there's some examples in [the xerces documentation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-pcfp.html#faq-4) but I'm not sure how to apply that to the spring case.

Comment: This is right, according to this reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/ (See 33.2.1)