# The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'

Tags: xml

I am new to XML Parsing and DTDs.
I was trying to create a simple SpringBean program and instantiate a class (Triangle.java) using the Spring.xml.

My DrawingApp.java looks like:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class DrawingApp {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("Spring.xml"));
    Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();
```

And my Spring.xml is like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<bean>
<bean id="triangle" class="org.kumarjivi.Triangle" />
</bean>
```

I googled and searched in earlier answers to the same problem on StackOverFlow and they tell something like disabling DTD validation ( which I think validating the DTD from the url given in the DOCTYPE line. I am able to access the dtd specified in url via web browser). But I don't have any idea about how to do that.

The exception I'm getting is:

```
Sep 22, 2014 3:13:25 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@145d068: startup date [Mon Sep 22 03:13:25 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 22, 2014 3:13:25 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 31 in XML document from class path resource [Spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.kumarjivi.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:16)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanEntityDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDecls(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd contains the lines

```
<!ENTITY % HTML.Version "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  -- Typical usage:

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    ... 43 lines ...

-->
```

which uses an obscure feature of SGML to include a lengthy comment. To an XML parser, that looks like the trailing `>` is missing.

That’s what’s causing this error message, but—

Delete the `<!DOCTYPE HTML...>` line from `spring.xml`. Spring XML files are not HTML and shouldn’t ever claim to be. HTML != XML.

Comment: I removed the whole <!DOCTYPE HTML...> line from Spring.xml but now when I try to run the program, it gives me another error 
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Users\kumar\workspace\SpringDemo\Spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 3 in XML document from file [C:\Users\kumar\workspace\SpringDemo\Spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'bean'. Should I add some <DOCTYPE..> to correctly parse XML file (earlier it was HTML)

Comment: @Jivi You could try http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd or see [How to use DOCTYPE in Spring XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378767/how-to-use-doctype-in-spring-xml-file)

Comment: I had tried this earlier (just by guess) but it was a space causing problem. This worked. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I do not have `<!DOCTYPE HTML...>` in my spring.xml. Still getting this error. Any guess?

Comment: Maybe a couple of years too late, but I must say that the entity definition in the official HTML 4.01 DTD is ***not*** missing the trailing `>`. The > is there, just a couple of lines down! The real problem is that XML files need a stricter version of the DTD syntax than HTML does; using the XHTML 1.0 Transitional DTD would not have been a problem for the parser.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince I don't believe you're getting the same error; the OP's is caused by parsing the DTD, which you are not.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince You are correct. I’ve updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me for latest Spring Framework v.4.2.1

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
```